# How to feed mysql queries from bash

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, unix, stdin

I'm trying to make a bash script that creates a mysql user and database but I can't find a way to feed the sql into mysql, I'm trying with this format:

```
mysql < echo "query"
```

But that is not working, see the example below:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=user --password=password < echo "CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY  'jakdJxct8W';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'testuser_dev' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  'testuser_dev' . * TO  'testuser'@'localhost';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'testuser_qa' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  'testuser_qa' . * TO  'testuser'@'localhost';"
```

How to feed mysql with the queries?

Comment: not related to the question, but you can also save a lot of typing by setting up your host, user and password in a .my.cnf file

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try like this:

```
echo "select 1" | mysql
```

Answer (score 30):

Try using a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) like this:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=user --password=password << END

CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY  'jakdJxct8W';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'testuser_dev' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  'testuser_dev' . * TO  'testuser'@'localhost';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'testuser_qa' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  'testuser_qa' . * TO  'testuser'@'localhost';

END
```

Alternatively place all you commands in text file and run it:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=user --password=password < commands.sql
```

Comment: +1 I'd also like to mention that if the query uses backticks, you need to quote the opening label: `mysql <<'END'`

Answer (score 26):

```
mysql --batch --silent -e 'SHOW TABLES';
```

Batch and silent are handy if you are planning to pipe the output

Comment: @cerd --batch without --silent shows column headers

Answer (score 12):

The reason your attempt did not work was because the `<` expects a file name and you fed it a string. You would have to do something like

```
echo "YOURQUERYSTRINGHERE">tmpfile
mysql --host=localhost --user=user --password=password dbname <tmpfile
```

ken's suggestion of

```
 mysql  --host=localhost --user=user --password=password -e "QUERY" dbname
```

can work, but if you try to use bash variables in your query you can fall foul of parameter expansion. eg

```
QUERY="select * from $MYTABLE WHERE name=\"silly@place.com\";"
mysql --host=localhost --user=user --password=password -e "$QUERY" mydbname
```

may not do what you expect.
One option is use

```
echo "$QUERY"|mysql --host=localhost --user=user --password=password mydbname
```

which works if the query string contains appropriate quoting. Another option is the "here" document as suggested by dogbane.

Comment: Good explanation of OP's error. Thanks for gathering others' responses and explaining caveats!

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried `mysql -e query`?

Answer (score 1):

```
cat <<EOD | mysql [-u user] [-ppassword] [database]
  select 1;
  select 2;
  select 3;
EOD
```

in your case

```
cat <<EOD | mysql -u root -p
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testuser_dev DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  testuser_dev.* TO  "testuser"@"localhost";
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testuser_qa DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  testuser_qa.* TO  "testuser"@"localhost";
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOD
```

Answer (score 0):

For big queries in a bash script, you can try:

```
read -d '' SQL_QUERY_1 << EOF

SELECT prod.id as id, prod.title as title, comp.name as company, pho.id as photo_id, pho.image as photo_name
FROM products as prod
JOIN accounts as comp
ON comp.id = prod.account_id
JOIN photos as pho
ON pho.id = prod.featured_photo_id;

EOF

echo ${SQL_QUERY_1} | mysql
```