# in linux bash is there a way to simulate a y keypress without the use of xte or other programs like it

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, keypress

what i'm trying to do in bash is install applications like apache mysql-server and wanted to know if there is way to program a "y press" so that I don't have to manually type y and then enter when it says 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?

thanks for the comment so for far 
i need to also do this to set up mysql but need to say n at the Disallow root login stage and change root password stage

also wondered if there is way to enter the following into mysql via the bash script 
CREATE DATABASE owncloud; #creates a database in mysql
GRANT ALL ON owncloud.* to 'owncloud'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'select_database_password';

i'm relatively new to shell scripting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150675/how-to-feed-mysql-queries-from-bash take a look here about mysql its already on stackoverflow. Generally its best to keep questions separated. and tagged accordingly to get attention from the relevant people

Comment: There's a convenient command called yes that prints its argument (which defaults to y) over and over again. There are better solutions, but if you're feeling lazy you can just type `$ yes | somecommand` and it will accept everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem you should solve with shell scripting.

See if your package manager has an option to assume "yes" for all question, e.g.

```
apt-get --assume-yes install apache mysql-server
```

Comment: ok thanks for that what's the best way to do this. i know the question said without xte but is this the standard practice

Comment: Working with your package manager and not against it, like in this example, is the standard and best practice. You don't say which distro you use, so I can't be more specific (this example works for Debian/Ubuntu/Mint).

Comment: `yes | command` may work in cases when the command doesn't have such an option.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at expect which can be used to automate a lot of tasks.

http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html