# Can we append output of a command to a table in mysql using bash script?

Tags: mysql, bash

I got a set of datas after executing sed command, now I want to append this output to my table in  mysql(not overwriting just append). But I am not sure if its possible. Any example?

```
sed -e "0,/$timestamp/d" /home/xxx/xx  > "To Mysql"
```

Comment: See: [How to feed mysql queries from bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6150675/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus I dnt want to overwrite my existing datas in my table. I just want to append new datas to my table with previous datas.

Comment: Then the SQL will be slightly different, but the concept of feeding something to MySQL from Bash will remain the same. If you need help with figuring out how to tell SQL to add something to an existing table, you need to articulate that in the question. (Hint: The SQL command `insert into`.)